# Implementing an Auto-Increment column in a DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to implement an auto-increment column in a DataFrame. 
I already found a solution but I want to know if there's a better way to do this.

I'm using `monotonically_increasing_id()` function from `pyspark.sql.functions`. 
The problem with this is that start at 0 and I want it to starts at 1.

So, I did the following and is working fine:

`(F.monotonically_increasing_id()+1).alias("songplay_id")`

```py
dfLog.join(dfSong, (dfSong.artist_name == dfLog.artist) & (dfSong.title == dfLog.song))\
                    .select((F.monotonically_increasing_id()+1).alias("songplay_id"), \
                               dfLog.ts.alias("start_time"), dfLog.userId.alias("user_id"), \
                               dfLog.level, \
                               dfSong.song_id, \
                               dfSong.artist_id, \
                               dfLog.sessionId.alias("session_id"), \
                               dfLog.location, \
                               dfLog.userAgent.alias("user_agent"))
```

Is there a better way to implement what im trying to do? 
I think, it's too much works to implement a udf function just for that or is just me?

Thanks.-

Comment: Unrelated, but you don't need `\` at the end of the lines for continuation when you are within parentheses.

Comment: I think your code is not guaranteeing to be consecutive numbers.

Comment: `monotonically_increasing_id` does not guarantee to result in a sequence of number

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sequence `monotonically_increasing_id` is not guaranted to be consecutive, but they are guaranted to be monotonically increasing. Each task of your job will be assigned a starting integer from which it's going to increment by 1 at every row, but you'll have gaps between the last id of one batch and the first id of another.
To verify this behavior, you can create a job containing two tasks by repartitioning a sample data frame:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame([[i] for i in range(10)], columns=['value'])) \
    .repartition(2) \
    .withColumn('id', psf.monotonically_increasing_id()) \
    .show()
        +-----+----------+
        |value|        id|
        +-----+----------+
        |    3|         0|
        |    0|         1|
        |    6|         2|
        |    2|         3|
        |    4|         4|
        |    7|8589934592|
        |    5|8589934593|
        |    8|8589934594|
        |    9|8589934595|
        |    1|8589934596|
        +-----+----------+
```

In order to make sure your index yields consecutive values, you can use a window function.

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window
w = Window.orderBy('id')
spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame([[i] for i in range(10)], columns=['value'])) \
    .withColumn('id', psf.monotonically_increasing_id()) \
    .withColumn('id2', psf.row_number().over(w)) \
    .show()
        +-----+---+---+
        |value| id|id2|
        +-----+---+---+
        |    0|  0|  1|
        |    1|  1|  2|
        |    2|  2|  3|
        |    3|  3|  4|
        |    4|  4|  5|
        |    5|  5|  6|
        |    6|  6|  7|
        |    7|  7|  8|
        |    8|  8|  9|
        |    9|  9| 10|
        +-----+---+---+
```

**Notes:**

- `monotonically_increasing_id` allows you to set an order on your rows as they are read, it starts at `0` for the first task and increases but not necessarily in a sequential manner
- `row_number` sequentially indexes the rows in an ordered window and starts at `1`